# Why does the live search not show up with live results in this script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

this is the header which contains the search box and the ul in which the live search results should be showing up. It prints the information about the data items out to the console, which means that the data can be found but it doesn't change anything in the ul which is linked to be altered when search results are found. I also checked the jsonSerialize function and it seems to be correct.

```js
<< ? php

//require_once('../Models/AuctionData.php');
require_once('../Models/AuctionDataSet.php');

$auctionDataSet = new AuctionDataSet();
$auctionDataSet = $auctionDataSet - > fetchSearch($_GET["q"]);



echo json_encode($auctionDataSet);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">


  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/my-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<script src="js/Script.js"></script>-->


  <title>Auction Website -
    <?php echo $view->pageTitle; ?>
  </title>
</head>

<body role="" document ">



<div class="container ">
        <div  class="row ">
            <div id="title " class="col-xs-12 ">
                <img src="images/iconhead.jpg "/>
                    <div class="pull-right "> <h1><?php echo $view->pageTitle ?> </h1></div>

            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="row ">
        <div id="menu " class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
        <ul class="nav navbar_default nav-stacked ">
            <li><a href="index.php ">Home </a></li>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
            {
            echo " <li><a href='Logout.php'>Logout</a></li>"; } else{ echo "
  <li><a href='Login.php'>Login</a></li>"; echo "
  <li><a href='Register.php'>Register</a></li>"; } ?>

  <form><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="search" placeholder="search">
  </form>


  <ul class="list-group" id="txtHint"></ul>





  </ul>
  </div>

  <script type=application/javascript>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", readyPage);

    function readyPage() {
      let searchIn = document.getElementById("search");
      searchIn.addEventListener("keyup", showHint);
      console.log("ready");
    }

    function showHint(event) {

      const text = event.target.value;
      console.log(event);
      let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


      let uic = document.getElementById("txtHint");
      if (text.length > 1) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Ajax/ajaxSearch.php?q=" + text);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return;
      }

      if (text.length < 2) {
        uic.innerHTML = "";
        return;
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

          let uic = document.getElementById("txtHint");
          uic.innerHTML = "";

          data.forEach(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj);

            uic.innerText += '<li class="list-group-item"><p>' + 'obj._id' + 'obj._title' + '</p>';

          });
        }

      };

    }
  </script>


  <div id="content" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
```

Comment: its `return`ing before applying the readystate event

Comment: oh yes I see it now, but how come it comes back with obj._id obj._title instead of the contents of the variables

Comment: because you wrapped your values in single quotes so they are strings, should be `<p>' + obj._id + obj._title + '</p>`

Comment: I know understand the importance of having a proper sleep schedule in order to function well, thank you sir